# Foreign key is now null and when mapping through the data it say "Attempt to read property "$category_name" on null"

Tags: laravel, null, foreign-keys, migration

I deleted a category which is an f-key of the items table. Now the view has an error saying 'Attempt to read property "category_name" on null'. How do I render a null foreign key?

I tried if-else:

```
@if({{$item->category->category_name}} === 'null')
  <h2>no category</h2>
 @else
  {{ $item->category->category_name}}
@endif
```

Comment: This is expected behavior, because $item->category is already null, you could use the null safe operator `$item->category?->category_name === null`. Otherwise you will have to check if $item->category is null and the name afterwards. But I suspect that you really just want and need to check if the category is null, so you could leave out the `->category_name` part

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@if ($item->category)
    {{ $item->category->category_name }}
@else
    <h2>no category</h2>
@endif
```

Or simply

```
<h2>{{ $item->category?->category_name ?? 'no category' }}</h2>
```

Comment: if you don't add the "?" after `$item->category` you will get the same error as the author

Answer (score 1):

In PHP8 or Larvel 8
simple use this one

```
<h2>{{ $item->category->category_name ? 'no category' }}</h2>
```